# Neo4j error when property name contains \u

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node which has a property named `authentication\username` but when I try to use the cypher like:

```
match (n) where n.`authentication\username` = 'user' return n
```

neo4j shows an error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input 's': expected four hexadecimal digits specifying a unicode character
```

what is wrong with that?

Thanks

Comment: please give me the command to create that property named authentication\username. How did you create it? And what is the version of your neo4j? thanks.

Comment: the node was created on neo4j 3.5.18 and the database was migrated , now we are using neo4j 4.4.6  and  just now we got this problem. 
Thanks

Comment: in neo4j 3.5.18 the command to create was like create (n:Person) set n.`authentication\username` = 'user' return n

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure, how this property got created, but now that it's there, it's pretty evident from the error message that `\u` in the property name is considered a `unicode character`. Directly matching, will not work here, so we will have to figure out the workarounds. I will suggest two workarounds, using a predicate function, `any`:

1. `match (n) where any(property IN keys(properties(n)) WHERE property = "authentication\\username" AND apoc.map.get(properties(n), property) = "user") return n`.
2. `match (n) where any(property IN keys(properties(n)) WHERE property STARTS WITH "authentication" AND property ENDS WITH "username" AND apoc.map.get(properties(n), property) = "user") return n`

In both the queries, we loop over the keys of the properties of a node.
In the first one, we look for the exact match of the key, notice I have escaped the `\` while matching. In the second one, we look for key starting with `authentication` and ending with `username`, since that suits our pattern. Finally, I read the matching key value, using `APOC` map function. So you need to have `APOC` library installed.

One of them should definitely work for you. Try them out.

Comment: so the nodes are created using the cypher CREATE (n:Person $props ) return n
where props parameter is a map like props={ "authentication\username"="user", "authentication\password"="124346" }

The workaround works fine,  I'm also able to query using 
match (n:Person) where n['authentication\\username'] = 'user' return n

but it looks like an issue , doesn´t it?

Comment: Maybe, you can post the same question on neo4j community, to know their views on it.